# After updating to wordpress 3.8 can't see thumbs in archive.php any more

Tags: wordpress

after updating to WP 3.8 I can't see anymore my thumbs in archive.php.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="post-entry">
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ); ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __( 'Pages:', 'responsive' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

In the functions.php I've added the following:

```
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

But nothing to do. The thumbnails still no more there.

Any help?

Thanks in advance,
Vince

Comment: Have you tried using only `the_post_thumbnail()` and seeing if the image shows up?

Comment: I tried it but no thumbnail to see. In the single post the images are shwon, in any other pages not.

Comment: I don't know why but for all others: My problem was solved with: http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-add-thumbnail/